# Checking if for-loop variable resides at two indexes of a list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, indexing, match

This may be difficult to explain. I want to specify two indexes, and then run a for loop. If the current `x` being checked in the loop is the *exact same item* specified at the location of the two indexes, then it should return a message.

```
array = [ [1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3], [4,4,4,4] ]
```

Again, here's my array. I want it to go through the for loop and print the message out when `x` is the `1` at memory of `array[0][0]`, aka the same piece of memory.

```
for x in array:
    if x == array[0][0]:
        print "%s is the object you're looking for." % x
```

Now, why I need it to make sure it is the same exact object in memory is because, this would loop through the following three 1's in the first list, and return the message too, as they have the same *value* as the first 1. I **do not** need this. I need only to match actual points in memory, not values.

Comment: Sheesh, this might be an easier explanation: Loop through the array (for x in array). If the current item being iterated (x) for is the same piece of memory as array[0][0], print a message. Not the same value! The same exact 1:1 variable in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking is how to test object *identity* rather than object *equality*.

In Python you can do this with the [`is` operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#is), i.e.

```
if x is y:
```

Rather than:

```
if x == y:
```

However, you're going have problems with ints and strings because the Python runtime automatically re-uses objects it creates for these from a pool:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1
>>> a is b
True
>>> id(a),id(b)
(13561552, 13561552)
```

I think short strings are automatically "interned" in this way and you can force longer strings to be using the [`intern()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#intern):

```
>>> c = 'Long string'
>>> d = 'Long string'
>>> c is d
False
>>> c = intern(c)
>>> d = intern(d)
>>> c is d
True
```

However, it seems the `long` type isn't interned so you use that:

```
>>> a = 1L
>>> b = 1L
>>> a is b
False
```

However, object identity for built-in types is down to the implementation of Python rather than being in the language, and is not something you should rely on either way.  I think you would be better off creating your own class of objects and writing an appropriate `__eq__` method for them, i.e. write your code it works based on object equality rather than identity.

Comment: Since Python reuses the same objects in memory for strings/numbers, do you think he could also use objects that store the values? eg `a = {'value':1}; b = {'value':1}` those are different objects and he can use the object references to do comparison and steal the value from `.value`. Or do you think `intern` is the better route?

Comment: So, there's no way to force a number or string to initialize with its own unique identity?

Comment: @Reznor - you could take @meder's suggestion and create your own objects to store the values or you could use `long` which doesn't seem to be interned.  However, if you are going to write your own class better to write one which behaves the way you want rather than relying on object identity which as we have seen is rather brittle.

Answer (score 0):

Actually x it's not a inner-tuple element, but a whole inner-tuple.

If I understood you well you want to print the whole tuple where the `index` element is the same as `array[container][index]` like this:

```
for subtuple in array:
    if subtuple[index] is array[container][index]:
        print "%s is the object you're looking for." % subtuple
```

Resulting in `[1, 1, 1, 1] is the object you're looking for.`

Answer (score 0):

a) these are Lists, not tuples and not arrays

b) 
 `for x in array:`

goes through the list "array", e.g. x is [1,1,1,1], then [2,2,2,2], ...
and that these are not at the position array[container][index] is clear, isn't it? (to be nitpicking, it would be possible for them to be there, because a list can contain itself, but I don't think that is what you want).

What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you're trying to do:

`for x in array:` means that `x` will first be `[1,1,1,1]` then `[2,2,2,2]` and so on.
On the other hand, `array[container][index]` can be only `1` ... how could they ever be equal?

Anyways, using `is` with numbers makes no sense to begin with. Maybe you should ask about the real problem ... ?